# JOIN query syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

hi everyone im beginner in php & mysql here im joining 3 tables but my query is not running as it is not right. thres is syntax error in it. please help, i would be thankful :))

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT   courses.id AS cid,
                                courses.title,
                                courses.subjectsid,
                                subjects.id AS sid,
                                subjects.subjectname,
                                requestrecord.status
                       FROM     courses,
                                subjects,
                                requestrecord
                       LEFTJOIN requestrecord
                         ON     courses.id = requestrecord.coursesid
                       WHERE   (courses.subjectsid = subjects.id )");
```

Comment: LEFTJOIN  instead try LEFT JOIN.

Comment: y iam getting negative points on this question? im new to this forum and dont knw what is it about..anyone who could tell me how i can gain points on this post??

Comment: @troublecreator Be sure to have read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq Questions related to a syntax error will usually be closed once the syntax error is pointed out, but rather than just saying something doesn't work, always include the following 1) What error message you receive 2) What you _expect_ the code should do 3) What the code is actually doing 4) What you have already tried to solve it.

Comment: If those 4 things are missing, you will likely incur downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a strange mix of implicit (WHERE clause) and explicit joins plus the syntax error with `LEFT JOIN`. It is recommended to settle on explicit joins only. Ultimately, your method proces two joins against `requestrecord`.

```
SELECT
  courses.id AS cid, 
  courses.title, courses.subjectsid,  
  subjects.id AS sid, 
  subjects.subjectname, 
  requestrecord.status 
FROM 
  courses 
  /* Explicit inner join against `subjects` */
  JOIN subjects ON courses.subjectsid = subjects.id
  /* LEFT JOIN against requestrecord */
  LEFT JOIN requestrecord ON courses.id = requestrecord.coursesid
```

Comment: thanks @Michael Berkowski problem is fixed..
i also want to know what if i want to display status record of the only student who is logged in...beacause its showing records of all the students as different students have applied for the same course...
any kind of help will be appreciated :)

Comment: @Riu2009 You will need to put the user's id in the `WHERE` clause. We can't see what that value would be based on the schema you have posted, but something like `WHERE users.id = {$logged_in_user_id}`

Comment: yeah i have the accounts id as foreign key in requestrecord table so i just equal it to SESSION id but that only shows the records having status applied against them...and i want to display list of all courses and a status if any... @Michael Berkowski

Comment: this is what i am doing.. 


    
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT courses.id AS cid,   
courses.title, courses.subjectsid, subjects.id AS sid, 
subjects.subjectname, requestrecord.accountsid, requestrecord.status 
FROM courses 
JOIN subjects 
ON courses.subjectsid = subjects.id 
LEFT JOIN requestrecord 
ON courses.id = requestrecord.coursesid
 WHERE requestrecord.accountsid=".$_SESSION['id']);

Comment: @Riu2009 Using `requestrecord` in the `WHERE` clause basically turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  If the user id is available in any other table beside `requestrecord`, use it instead.

Comment: yeah userid is in accounts table so o should join accounts table as well to get user id??? @Michael Berkowski  thankyou so much for ur response

Comment: @Riu2009 Yep, add an inner join against `accounts` and use that in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: this is what iam doing but getting syntax error @Michael Berkowski 
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT courses.id AS cid, courses.title, courses.subjectsid, subjects.id AS sid, subjects.subjectname,  requestrecord.status, accounts.id
FROM courses JOIN subjects ON courses.subjectsid = subjects.id 
LEFT JOIN requestrecord 
ON courses.id = requestrecord.coursesid 
WHERE accounts.id=".$_SESSION['id']);`

Comment: @Riu2009 You have no `JOIN` against `accounts`.  You need to join it against something.

Comment: fixed that error @Michael Berkowsk but its not doing what i want...its showing applied statuses of other students as well..sorry for bothering you..need help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18746/discussion-between-riu2009-and-michael-berkowski)

Comment: @Riu2009 This is now outside the scope of your original question.  You should ask a new question, and post your schema

Comment: y iam getting negative points on this question? im new to this forum and dont knw what is it about..anyone who could tell me how i can gain points on this post??

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the LEFT JOIN issue, you are also joining to the requestrecord table twice (once as an implicit cartesian join). Try:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT courses.id AS cid, courses.title, courses.subjectsid,  subjects.id AS sid, subjects.subjectname, requestrecord.status FROM courses JOIN subjects ON courses.subjectsid = subjects.id LEFT JOIN requestrecord ON courses.id = requestrecord.coursesid");
```

Comment: y iam getting negative points on this question? im new to this forum and dont knw what is it about..anyone who could tell me how i can gain points on this post??

Comment: @troublecreator: I have not voted you down. A question for those people who have downvoted you might be better asked as a comment against your own question. One thing that might have helped would have been to included the error message returned when trying to run the query. You could also check the reasons given by the users who closed your question. Further advice on asking questions on StackOverflow can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @ Mark Bannister thanx for ur response..how i would know about the ppl who voted it down?? so that i could ask them.. :(

Comment: @troublecreator: You could try adding a comment to your question, asking for downvoters to leave comments explaining their votes. Beyond that, there isn't any way to get direct feedback from them.